# iterating and writing to mysql from unix

Tags: mysql, shell, scripting

I'm trying to iterate through a delimited text file and insert those into a mysql DB table using a shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS='|' read val1 val2 val3
#cat testfile.txt | while read line
do
    #val1=`echo $line | cut -d'|' -f1`
    #val2=`echo $line | cut -d'|' -f2`
    #val3=`echo $line | cut -d'|' -f3`
    echo $val1 $val2 $val3
    /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --user=root --password= test << EOF
    insert into addressTable(street,city,zip)values('$val1','$val2','$val3')
    EOF
done < testfile.txt
```

The content of the testfile.txt would be

```
abc|xyz|123
def|uvw|456
```

On running the script i'm getting a `./testMySQL.sh: line 12: syntax error: unexpected end of file` error.

If i comment out the code that connects to the mysql and the subsequent insert statement, the script works fine and just displays the content.

I believe the way i'm iterating the file might be causing it, but not sure what i'm missing here.

Comment: Is the "<<" in before EOF clashing with the `while` ???

Comment: Try adding a '-' like `<<-EOF` (just that, nothing else ;-) ). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Saying:

```
while IFS='|' read val1 val2 val3
```

causes the variables `val1`, `val2`, `val3` to be set (assuming that your input is of the form you've described).

Commenting or deleting the following lines should fix the issue:

```
val1=`echo $line | cut -d'|' -f1`
val2=`echo $line | cut -d'|' -f2`
val3=`echo $line | cut -d'|' -f3`
```

The above lines would have been required if you had said:

```
while read line
```

instead of

```
while IFS='|' read val1 val2 val3
```

Comment: Thanks devnull. I was switching between the `while` and `cat`. But the problem still exists. Updated the code snippet to reflect my latest attempt.

Comment: @user2241559 Can you try running `dos2unix` on your script as well as the input file (testfile.txt).